# EJB - Could not register a EJB receiver for connection to host

Tags: java, ejb

In our company we been using ejb in all applications. We have about 25 applications which worked without problem until today. Today we are getting an error:

> [org.jboss.ejb.client.remoting.ConfigBasedEJBClientContextSelector]
>   (default task-4)  Could not register a EJB receiver for connection to
>   ip: java.lang.RuntimeException: Operation failed with status WAITING

And we have this error in all applications. Sometimes they start working for several minutes but they are too slow. Most of the time they don't work. Does someone have any idea what have happened?

Comment: Can you post a code example for the client code? Are you aware of any changes at the infrastructure level that may be causing issues? Is the remote host where the EJB run available / healthy?

Comment: Since yesterday we have found that there is problem between server2server communication while trying to use Ejb protocol. Ping goes between servers. e.g one of our applications which has web and ejb(ear) module on the same machine client url was configured like this: remote.connection.1.host=network_ip. After I have changed it to remote.connection.1.host=127.0.0.1 it started working.

Comment: I know that sounds like network or firewall issue, but network and sysadmins have argued that there is not firewall active or no network restrictions between servers

Comment: [`ping` uses ICMP protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ping_%28networking_utility%29) so the fact `ping` works between hosts does not necessarily imply that other packages using different protocols will reach their destination. What about software firewalls running on the hosts themselves? The fact that you were not able to connect from machine A to machine A using `network_ip` but were able to do so by switching to `localhost` does suggest there is some level of filtering going on.

Comment: You mention that things suddenly stopped working. Are you aware of any changes at the OS or application server level that may have changed previous configurations? What application server are you using? What protocol are you using to contact EJBs remotely?